# Could not connect to server. Check that the host name and port values are correct

Tags: java

I'm trying to use **Coverity Connect** in **eclipse** for **code analysis**.

I installed **plugins** related to **Coverity** in my eclipse.

> When I go to Windows -> Preferences -> Coverity Analysis,

It's asking **host name, port, user name and password.**

After entering all details, when I click **Test Connection**, following popup message is showing

> "Could not connect to server. Check that the host name and port values
>   are correct".

I installed **cov-analysis-win32-6.5.1** in my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to connect to? From what it sounds like, you're trying to connect to someone else's computer or server (potentially a home computer?), but I'm gonna need some clarification on that if not. If that's the case, most likely they don't have port forwarding enabled, so other people can't connect to their computer.

http://www.howtogeek.com/66214/how-to-forward-ports-on-your-router/

Comment: Yes I am trying to connect to other computer.In the browser I am able to connect and login using the same credentials which I am using in eclipse Windows -> Preferences -> Coverity Analysis. In browser it is working fine but in eclipse it is not working.This is basically for Coverity code analysis for java.

Comment: Hi, I am able to resolve the above issue. I added latest plugins related to Coverity into my eclipse.  Thank you